# Java JComboBox select index

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have this section of code:

```
String[] emailList = { "Choose an email type", "yahoo.com", "gmail.com", "mail.com", "OTHER"};
JComboBox emailComboBox = new JComboBox (emailList);
registerPanel.add(emailComboBox);
emailComboBox.setBounds(350, 286, 173, 20);
```

How can I do when the user select the index 0 or 4 (Choose.. and Other) to do something.

Comment: Your question can more readily be answered by visiting one or more tutorials, like [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for example.  The question in hand has probably also been asked and answered before.  If you've read those tutorials and are still having trouble, then please provide some more details about how you tried to apply the concepts from the tutorials and other answers so we can see what you have done wrong

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: The question is how i know when someone select the index 4 (OTHER) if (emailComboBox.setSelectedIndex(4) ) don't work

Comment: [`JComboBox#getSelectedIndex`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedIndex--) or use [`JComboBox#getSelectedItem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem--) and check it against `"OTHER"`, the second which is demonstrated in the duplicate and both which are demonstrated in the tutorials and listed in the JavaDocs